# Differentiation consistency in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, handle, consistency, differentiation

I'm trying to write a program in matlab that checks how consistent the definition of the derivative becomes:

```
(f(x+h)-f(x))/h ~= f'(x)
```

when `h` is small enough. Thus far i have this:

```
function [errList] = diffConsistency(f,df,x,iMax,h0)
h=h0;
for i=1:iMax
    leftSide = (f(x+h) - f(x)) / h;
    rightSide = df(x);
    errList = abs(leftSide - rightSide);
    h = h*10^(-1);
end
```

I then use `f=@(x)sin(x)` and `df=@(x)cosx`, I'm new to using function handles so this might be wrong completely. `iMax` is set to `10` and `h0 = 1`, `x=rand(10)`

Could anyone check if this is even remotely correct. Especially the use of the function handles inside the diffConsistency function and use of the `rand`.

Should i define x differently, leftside rightside are correct? etc

Any feedback would help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How have you tested this so far? Does it work for sin(x) and cos(x)? Does it work for cases where the function don't match (try it for f = sin(x) and df = sin(x), say)?

Comment: It does not work as i hoped, since the error fluctuates too much and does not converge to something

Comment: Could you edit the question then to give an example of the output for various values of `h`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use some specific data that obscures the result. You input 10x10 random numbers, and output a 10x10 matrix of errors, but this is only for the last `i`, as you overwrite `errList` every iteration!

change the function to:

```
function [errList] = diffConsistency(f,df,x,iMax,h0)
h=h0;
for i=1:iMax
    leftSide = (f(x+h) - f(x)) / h;
    rightSide = df(x);
    errList(i) = abs(leftSide - rightSide);
    h = h*10^(-1);
end
```

and if you call it as :

```
err=diffConsistency(@sin,@cos,rand,10,1)
```

and `plot(err)`, you can clearly see how the error gets reduced each smaller `h`.

Comment: Done. I do however have one more question. When I set iMax to 100 my error decreases until a certain value (around 10^-8), but then it starts increasing again. I do not know how to explain this. Is it a flaw in the code, number loss or something else entirely?

Comment: @p.late dangerous place you are getting into, careful careful! This has to do with computers, and floating point arithmetic. You can not store arbitrarily small numbers in a computer, as it has limited memory. When you reach 1e-12 you are starting to get into dangerous area where accuracy of the computation is not reliable anymore. You are saying you are trying to compute 1e-100 (`h`). Read more about why this happens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab)

Comment: Ah I see. What do you think would be an appropriate value to give iMax in this case? By the way I adapted my code with the following break statement:

Comment: if h < 2^(-52)
        
break

    end